# Identifying indentity column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity

I have found that how to determine what columns are primary key column of a given table by using this query:

```
 SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
 FROM
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
 WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename_here' AND
 CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK_%'
```

I can find , what the identity seed and increment is by using this query:

```
SELECT IDENT_SEED('tablename_here'), IDENT_INCR('tablename_here')
```

I cant use the constraint information, because a primary key constraint can be across multiple columns. And i cant seem to find any Transact SQL function to give my the identity information.

Can anybody help me to understand how to find the identity information?

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find the IDENTITY column in a given table you can use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename_here' 
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('tablename_here'),COLUMN_NAME,'IsIdentity') = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [COLUMNPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx) function to check whether a column uses the identity property.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sys.tables.name, sys.columns.name
FROM sys.tables
INNER JOIN sys.columns
ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
WHERE is_identity = 1
AND sys.tables.name = 'MyTable'
```